# Refresh part of a form after Ajax Call in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, simple-form

I have a form that creates a new Order. One of the form elements is an address dropdown, that lets the user choose an address from the Address model. I have set it up, so that a user can create an Address via an Ajax modal by pressing a button right in the Order form.
Everything works EXCEPT for the part where I want to refresh the dropdown in the Order form after creating the new address via Ajax.

My (partially edited) code is as follows:

Orders Controller

```
def new
  @order = Order.new
end
```

Addresses Controller

```
def new
  @address = Address.new(user: current_or_guest_user)
  respond_with @address
end

def create
  @address = Address.new(address_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @address.save
      format.js   { render action: 'show_address_ajax', status: :created, location: @address }
    else
      render json: @address.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end
```

Order View (includes Order form)

```
<%= simple_form_for @order do |f| %>
<div class="row address_dropdown" id="address1_dropdown">
  <%= render "address1", f: f %>
</div>
<%= link_to ('New Address'), new_address_path,
  data: { modal: true }, class: "btn btn-default", id: "new-pickup-address" %>

<%= f.button :submit, "Save Order", class: 'btn-lg' %>
```

Address Dropdown Partial ('orders/_address1.html.erb')

```
<%= f.association :address, label: false, collection: current_or_guest_user.addresses.pluck(:nombre, :id), prompt: "Select Address", :input_html => { :class => '' } %>
```

Javascript to render partial ('show_address_ajax.js.erb')

```
$("#address1_dropdown").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'orders/address1, locals: { f: f }) %>");
```

Order Form renders ok, Address modal form (not shown for simplicity) also renders ok and creates new address, but the problem is that I am unable to refresh the Address dropdown in the order form after Ajax call completes, as the f variable is undefined everywhere but in the Order view.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: your `link_to` executes the action `addresses#new`, that responds with `@address`. You need to explain hear the logic of your code. I think you made it a little bit complicated, I don't really think that you need `AJAX` for this. Usually you can just ask the user to build a new `address`. `address belongs_to order`, so you can create a nested form. When the user creates the address, he can either select an existing one or create a new one with the `nested form`. To select one you just use the `association` with simple form. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

Comment: once the user saves, both will be saved to the db, but if you want to go forward with `AJAX`, you are not explaining us any logic from your code. I know that `link_to` triggers the `addresses#new`, but then how is `addresses#create` triggered? why do you name the `javascript` as `show_addresses_ajax.js.erb` and then you call it after `addresses#create`. This is not the best practice from ROR and you are confusing me http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#server-side-concerns

Comment: the js file should be named `create.js.erb`